# What does `Dv` mean in $F\star$ language?

Tags: proof-assistants, fstar

In the $F\star$ [tutorial](https://fstar-lang.org/tutorial/) it says

> `Dv`, the effect of a computation that may diverge;

what does *diverge* mean here? It's not explained and it confuses me.

I guess it means the type consists but the value varies, but if so why there isn't a non-diverge non-terminate effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the theory of computation "diverge" means "does not terminate" or "runs forever". This is a computational effect (of a peculiar kind).